# How can I most beautifully apply the methods of a parent class to all (registered) instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance, design-patterns

For ease of programming, I am looking to implement something like this:
    SpecialCaseChildClass.apply_to_all_members_of_child_class.any_method_of_parent()

Even more awesome would be an implementation in which I can supply a list of arguments that allows me to iterate arguments:

```
SpecialCaseChildClass.apply_to_all.any_method_of_Parent(
argument1_of_parent_method = range(number_of_children), argument2_of_parent_method = range(number_of_children))
```

So my suggestion in words: (How) can I put an apply_to_all_members_of_class object/method between child and parent methods in command chain?

I have tried to implement this functionality with a class method:

```
class SpecialCaseChildClass(Parent):

    registry = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs, *args):
        super().__init__(self, **kwargs, *args)
        registry.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def apply_to_all(cls, any_function, *args, **kwargs):
        [any_function(child, *args, **kwargs) for child in cls.registry]
```

which would allows the following:

```
SpecialCaseChildClass.apply_to_all_members_of_child_class(ParentClass.any_Parent_method, *args, *kwargs)
```

but that is not as pretty as simple addition to the chain.

Is such a thing possible relatively simply?

Is it even desirable?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use a list comprehension instead of this `apply_to_all` method? Basically you'd do something like `[obj.any_Parent_method(range(x), range(y)) for obj in SpecialCaseChildClass.registry]` instead of `SpecialCaseChildClass.apply_to_all.any_Parent_method(range(x), range(y))`.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your reply. What I meant with that notation is that range(x)[n] would be passed to instance in registry[n], not the whole range.
The reason I want to make a chain with "."'s is because I will need to apply methods to all instances flexible and many many times. I think using a list comprehension will make the code less comprehensible. In fact, I want to treat the instances in a vector-like way (all are widgets on a screen, that I want to update simultaneously upon an event).

Comment: Unrelated, but do NOT use list comprehensions for side effects - only if you really want to build a list and use it.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean that a for loop ought to be used? Can you explain why? After your reply, I will edit the code above :)